# "by the six month mark" vs "by the six month"

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.lingq.com/lesson/lesson-18-analyzing-cost-benefits-431411/

***By the six month mark, the company should be making a profit.***

in the above context, the word **"mark"** seems redundant. If it is not, then, what is the difference between "by the six month" and "by the six month mark"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *mark* is necessary here because "By the six month" is ungrammatical.

**Mark**, in this case, means ["a figure registering a point or level reached or achieved"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mark).  "The *six month mark*" (which might be better written as "*six-month* mark") is a phrase that uses a *[noun adjunct](http://tx.english-ch.com/teacher/chris/level-b/grammar-in-use-noun-adjuncts/)*, a noun or nouns used to modify another noun:  The company has reached a mark.  What kind of mark?  A *six-month* mark.

If you didn't want to use the word *mark*, you could legitimately say "by the ___ month", but you would have to say "by the **sixth** month", not "by the *six* month", because when counting the position of things in a list we use [ordinal numbers](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/ordinal-vs-cardinal-numbers) like *first, second, third* and not cardinal numbers like *one, two, three*.

The author might have chosen to use "the six month mark" instead of "the sixth month" because "the sixth month" might be confusing - the sixth month of what?  June is the sixth month of the year; does he mean that?